# In an Ubuntu VM setup through vftool on M1 Mac, the arrow keys and ⌘+V keys are not working

Tags: terminal, unix, virtualization

I have setup an Ubuntu VM on and M1 Mac using [vftool](https://github.com/evansm7/vftool). The VM loads and works, however on Ubuntu, in a terminal, the arrow keys and paste (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) are not working.

In place of arrow keys it prints `^[[C`, `^[[D`.

Also <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> pastes copied text which is prefixed by similar character shown above.

Comment: Would this not depend on the which type terminal you are emulating, the type of terminal the shell thinks you are using and perhaps type type of shell you are using?

Comment: ESC-[-C and ESC-[-D are the control codes for let and right arrow.  Using ⌘+v for paste would be the host OS's paste, not the VM's paste.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out actual cause for this issue.
When VM is started with -t 0 command line argument of Vftool arrow keys shows escape characters.
If vm is started without -t 0 (default 1), there is no issue with arrow keys.

Comment: See the docs https://github.com/evansm7/vftool - t 0 uses simple stdout/in and so everything is plain text and -t 1 the default is a terminal you can type in

Comment: Yes already seen this docs in github.com/evansm7/vftool